# spring & web service client - Fault Detail

Tags: spring, service, webservicetemplate

How could I get the Fault Detail sent by a SoapFaultClientException ?
I use a WebServiceTemplate as shown below :

```
WebServiceTemplate ws = new WebServiceTemplate();
ws.setMarshaller(client.getMarshaller());
ws.setUnmarshaller(client.getUnMarshaller());
try {
    MyResponse resp = (MyResponse) = ws.marshalSendAndReceive(WS_URI, req);
} catch (SoapFaultClientException e) {
     SoapFault fault =  e.getSoapFault();
     SoapFaultDetail details = e.getSoapFault().getFaultDetail();
      //details always NULL ? Bug?
}
```

The Web Service Fault sent seems correct :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
     <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Validation error</faultstring>
     <faultactor/>
     <detail>
        <ws:ValidationError xmlns:ws="http://ws.x.y.com">ERR_UNKNOWN</ws:ValidationError>
     </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Thanks

Willome

Comment: Problem was coming from the JAXB Libraries

Answer (score 9):

I also had the problem that getFaultDetail() returned null (for a SharePoint web service). I could get the detail element out by using a method similar to this:

```
private Element getDetail(SoapFaultClientException e) throws TransformerException {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
    transformer.transform(e.getSoapFault().getSource(), result);
    NodeList nl = ((Document)result.getNode()).getElementsByTagName("detail");
    return (Element)nl.item(0);
}
```

After that, you can call getTextContent() on the returned Element or whatever you want.

Answer (score 6):

Check out what type of HTTP response you get when receiving Soap Fault. I had the same problem when SOAP Fault responses using HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 500. Then you get:

> JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is
>   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

When you change WebServiceTemplate connection fault settings as below:

```
WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = getWebServiceTemplate();
webServiceTemplate.setCheckConnectionForFault(false);
```

then you can properly catch **SoapFaultClientException**

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadocs for the [marshalSendAndReceive method](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceOperations.html#marshalSendAndReceive%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)
it looks like the SoapFaultClientException in the catch block will never happen.

From the API it looks like the best bet for determining the details of the fault is to set a custom [Fault Message Receiver](http://static.springframework.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html#setFaultMessageResolver%28org.springframework.ws.client.core.FaultMessageResolver%29).

Comment: SoapFaultClientException in the catch block will happen. The throws part as stated in the javadocs is WebServiceClientException. SoapFaultClientException is a subclass of that exception.